# How to define function in Scala that returns a function that itself returns a function

Tags: scala

I have defined the following identity function:-

```
def identity(n: Int) = n
```

Now I am defining a function `funA` that returns this `identity` function:-

```
def funA(): (Int => Int) = identity
```

This works fine. Basically, I am saying here that the function which I am returning actually accepts `Int` and returns `Int`.

Now I want to take it further. I want to define another function `funB`, which should return `funA`. My problem is that now the return type won't be `(Int => Int)`. Unlike `funA` which returned a function accepting `Int` and returning `Int`, now I want to return a function `(funA)` which doesn't accept anything and returns a function and not an integer. So how do I syntactically write this in Scala?

Comment: `identity` and `funA` are methods, not functions. It's not clear what you want. You can't return a method because methods aren't objects and you can only return objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`funA` is a parameterless method that returns `Int => Int`. Therefore, as a function it will have type `() => (Int => Int)`. If `funB` is to also be a parameterless method that returns `funA`, it would look like this:

```
def funB(): () => (Int => Int) = funA
```

If you were to take this further (for whatever reason), as a function, `funB` would have type

```
() => (() => (Int => Int)))
```

And so on..

Comment: Note, type signatures in Scala are right associative, which means in this case it is not necessary to surround them by parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

```
def funB(): (()=> Int=>Int) = funA
```

You can't write directly def funB() = funA though, because this will be give funB the same signature as funA.